# Installing nodejs on Red Hat

Tags: node.js, redhat, yum

I am trying to install node.js on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.1 using the following command:

```
sudo yum install nodejs npm
```

I got the following error:

```
Error: Package: nodejs-0.10.24-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: nodejs-devel-0.10.24-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: nodejs-0.10.24-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: nodejs-devel-0.10.24-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried the following command as well:

```
sudo yum install -y nodejs
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Package: nodejs-0.10.24-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: nodejs-0.10.24-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
```

How should I install it? I want to install the latest version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to update your version of CentOS 6 to 6.5+ or at least your copy of OpenSSL because the node.js package provided for CentOS 6 was [compiled on a system that had a newer version of OpenSSL](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1048982#c1) which is available in 6.5+.

The alternative is to compile and install node manually from source or use the precompiled binaries from nodejs.org.

Answer (score 33):

NodeJS provides a setup script that must run before you install it with yum

```
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
```

Then the yum command should work

```
yum install -y nodejs
```

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager#enterprise-linux-and-fedora

Comment: Hi, I used this way, but the 'No package nodejs available.' still happends? What could I do? thanks

Comment: The script above will soon be deprecated in favour of version specific scripts:
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -

Comment: @liamxu I had the same problem. Solution was I forgot `-E`in sudo. If you do not run as root and for example use a https_proxy you have to use `sudo -E bash -` after the pipe. As written in the scripts intro itself but overlooked by me for quite some time

Answer (score 13):

I don't have the rep to comment on jfredys' answer, but wanted to add an addendum. His answer is correct for certain environments I assume, but it failed for me as I was running into the error:

**Your distribution, identified as "redhat-release-server-6Server-6.6.0.2.el6.x86_64", is not currently supported, please contact NodeSource at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues if you think this is incorrect or would like your distribution to be considered for support**

I had run into weirdness trying to install meteor packages on another server recently and it turned out to be a proxy/firewall issue with curl trying to hit SSL sites. I had to alter all curl commands to use -k to bypass false SSL warnings. First I copied the install script locally:

```
curl -kL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup > ~/nodeInstall.sh
```

While I was at it I removed the s (silent) option to give some insight into any problems (fortunately there were none). In the script I changed all the curl commands to use -k (also removed the silent option just in case). I set it executable and this ran cleanly (under sudo), I was then finally able to install npm with

```
sudo yum install -y nodejs
```

And all was happy:

```
$npm -version
1.4.28
```

Answer (score 6):

Just as per https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/ you have to launch:

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
```

or

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
```

depending on NodeJS version you need. Then simply run

```
yum -y install nodejs
```

Comment: `sudo su root -` and `curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | bash -` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

If this command is not working then visit:

https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup

in your browser.

It gives instructions on how to use wget instead:

```
wget -qO- https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO the answer by @Eric Soyke should be marked as the correct one. One thing to change in case you want node v4, is to replace 'setup' with 'setup_4.x'.

The sequence of commands (at least for a root user) is this:

```
curl -kL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup > ~/nodeInstall.sh
# or for v4 / v6:
#  curl -kL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x > ~/nodeInstall.sh
#  curl -kL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x > ~/nodeInstall.sh
sed -i -e 's_curl _curl -k _g' nodeInstall.sh
chmod u+x nodeInstall.sh
./nodeInstall.sh
yum -y install nodejs
rm nodeInstall.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `dnf` to install the version of NodeJS you need because `yum` will likely pull the wrong version. As seen [Here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-node-js-on-redhat-8-linux)

List the available versions;

```
sudo dnf module list nodejs
```

Install the one you want:

```
sudo dnf module install nodejs:14
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following commands:

```
sudo dnf install curl
```

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash
```

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

```
nvm install v21.6.1
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. Run both commands as super user.

```
sudo curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -

sudo yum install -y nodejs
```